# SSL cert for sub.domain.me and www.sub.domain.me

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I got ssl cert from let's encrypt for `domain.me` and `www.domain.me` using this [tutorial on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04). 
Everything worked fine.
Then I've created `sub.domain.me` and `www.sub.domain.me` and tried to get ssl certs for them using the same steps. 
`sub.domain.me` works fine. But when I try to get `www.sub.domain.me` in browser  the error occures:

```
Your connection is not private. NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am not using a wildcard certificate, as LetsEncrypt does not support this

`server` block which causes the problem look like:

```
server {
    listen:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.sub.domain.me;
    return 301 $sheme://sub.domain.me$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Are all for of these on the same certificate?

Comment: @PeterReid as far as I understand domain.me and www.domain.me have one certificate. sub.domain.me and www.sub.domain.me have another.

Comment: are `sum.domain.me`/`www.sub.domain.me` and `domain.me`/`www.domain.me` all meant to be pointing at the same site?

Comment: @PeterReid yes. All of them are Nginx server blocks.

Comment: can you paste your nginx config please?

Comment: @PeterReid ohh. It seems that the problem is caused by nginx config. When I try to redirect users  from WWW to nonWWW subdomain. Frankly speaking I can't understand the reason of such behavour. I've edited the question text and added the server block that causes the issue.

Comment: can you include the certificate specification lines from your config

Comment: @PeterReid `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.me/fullchain.pem;` 
`ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.me/privkey.pem;`

Comment: So you aren't loading the certificate for both?

Comment: @PeterReid Do you mean these two in my previous comment or all ssl params?

Comment: So if you have two separate SSL certs you'll need to be loading them both

Comment: @PeterReid yes I do not load both certificates because it is not needed as far as I understand. I've generated them with command `sudo certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/sub.domain.me -d sub.domain.me -d www.sub.domain.me`. This means that there is one certificate for both of them, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PeterReid but I have the same certificate specification line for `domain.me`/`www.domain.me` and it works fine. When I remove redirect block from nginx config it also works fine for `sub.domain.me`/`www.sub.domain.me`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/server.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/server.key;
```

to server block ( of course with Your path and file names ). If subdomains have other certificate, use path to them.

But it's hard to say what is wrong without all nginx config

Comment: Yes. I've added `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` to `server` block which redirects users from www to nonWWW and now everything works fine. I can't understand why it works without these two lines on main domain.

Comment: It's hard to say when I do not see Your config.

Comment: Personally I had problem because when I wrote http:// example.com it correctly redirect to https:// www.example.com, but when I wrote https:// www.example.com nginx redirect to https:// example.com. So I need to create one more server block to redirect nonWWW listening on 443 ssl to www.